# If $AB$ and $BA$ are invertible matrices, are $A$ and $B$ square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Two matrices $A$ ($n \times m$) and $B$ ($m \times n$). $AB$ and $BA$ are invertible. Is $m=n$ necessarily?

I had this question in a test and I think this is true but I'm not sure. I used the ranks of the matrices and the fact $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B))$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the inequalities $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\}$ and $\operatorname{rank}(BA) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\} \ (\star)$. Also we have $\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B) \leq \min\{m,n\}$

Since $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n \times m$ matrix it follows that $AB$ is a $m \times m$ matrix and $BA$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. The fact that $AB$ and $BA$ are invertible means that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=m$ and $\operatorname{rank}(BA)=n$.

Therefore using $(\star)$ you obtain the inequalities $\max\{m,n\} \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\} \leq \min\{m,n\}$. This implies $m=n$.

Answer (score 9):

$AB$ invertible implies $A$ surjective and $B$ injective... So with $BA$ invertible, you have it.

Comment: Nice argument involving linear applications.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ provides a linear map $K^m \to K^n$ and $B$ provides a linear map which is inverse to this linear map. Hence $K^n \cong K^m$, i.e. $n=m$.